# Nonconstructible Algebraic Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

What is an example of an algebraic number that is not Euclideanly constructible (meaning that no series of basic arithmetic operations or the taking of roots can produce the number)?

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible.

Comment: That's constructible in the straightedge and compass sense. I'm not sure @kevin means that sense. Or do you?

Comment: What senses are there?

Comment: @IanColey: you mean, that's *not* constructible in the straightedge and compass sense.

Comment: @xyzzyz When Ian says "that", he means "that notion of constructible", not the number itself.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Mike. I need better antecedents.

Answer (score 5):

It's a well known result of Galois theory that given an irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, its roots can be expressed as elementary algebra operations and taking roots only if it's Galois group over $\mathbb{Z}$ is solvable, that is, has finite subnormal series with cyclic factors -- obviously taking roots corresponds to taking cyclic extension, and other operations don't require extending the field. In other direction, it's well known that any cyclic extension correspond to taking a root.

So, it's enough to find a polynomial with unsolvable Galois group. I say that 
$$
x^5 + 5x + 1
$$
is such polynomial. It is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion. We'll show that its Galois group is $S_5$, which is unsolvable (because the only normal subgroup of $S_5$ is $A_5$ which is simple nonabelian).

First, we'll see that not all roots are real. Indeed, if it was the case, then the sum of squares of roots $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 + x_5^2$ would be strictly positive (since $0$ is not a root). But since for a polynomial $x^5 + a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + dx + e$, the sum of roots $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5$ is equal to $-a$, and sum of all products of two roots $\sum_{i,j} x_i x_j$ is equal to $2b$, we see that since for our polynomial $a = b = 0$, $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 + x_5^2 = (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5)^2 - \sum_{i,j} x_i x_j = -a + 2b = 0$, so not all roots are real. Since coefficients of our polynomial are real, the complex conjugation gives an element of Galois group of order two.

Adjoining one root of $x^5 + 5x + 1$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ gives us extension of degree $5$, so adjoining all roots of this polynomial to get a splitting field must give us extension of degree divisible by $5$. Since this degree is equal to the order of Galois group, it must thus also be divisible by $5$, and so since $5$ is prime, by Cauchy theorem, it has an element of order $5$.

Now, we know that Galois group of polynomial of degree $n$ embeds in $S_n$, so Galois group of our polynomial embeds in $S_5$, contains an element of order 2 -- a transposition, and also an element of order $5$ -- a full cycle. It's well known and easy to see that these two are enough to generate whole $S_5$, so our Galois group is $S_5$, which is not solvable.